# How to dynamically create objects with variables

Tags: javascript

I have some variables in a loop which are different each iteration.

With those variables I want to fill a new object with some sub objects like so:

```
newProduct[key][prop][val] = "value";
```

What I want is an object like

```
car{ //key
   color: { //prop
       door: "value" //val + value
   }
}
```

But my problem is that `[val]` is not an object from `[prop]` and that is what Node.JS is trying to do.

I have tried it some other brackets like `[prop[val]]` and `[prop + "." + val]`, but that doesn't seems to work. 
How can I get this to work?

Comment: I think you need to show us what do you have and what do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with Object assign like that:

```js
// It should be every iteration values
var key = 'car';
var prop = 'color';
var val = 'door';
var value = 'value';

var newProduct = Object.assign({ [ key ] :{ [ prop ] : { [ val ] : value }} });
console.log(newProduct);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could check every property and use a default object. Later assign the value

```js
function setValue(object, path, value) {
    var last = path.pop();
    path.reduce((o, k) => o[k] = o[k] || {}, object)[last] = value;
}

var newProduct = {};

setValue(newProduct, ['car', 'color', 'door'], 42);

console.log(newProduct);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create each object at each layer before you can use it. Here's a very simple example. You could refine it to make it more re-usable, obviously:

```js
var newProduct = {};
if (!newProduct["car"]) newProduct["car"] = {};
if (!newProduct["car"]["color"]) newProduct["car"]["color"] = {};
newProduct["car"]["color"]["door"] = "value";
console.log(newProduct);
```